# How to access file information in a pre-commit hook using SharpSVN

Tags: svn, sharpsvn, pre-commit-hook

I am new to SharpSVN and SVN in general. I am trying to implement a pre-commit hook that when the user commits a certain type of XML file; I am going to need to intercept the file and analyze it to ensure they included certain elements before I allow the file to be committed.

Since it seems that SVN submits two arguments; the repository path and the transaction; I will need to use these two items to intercept the file. Does anyone know what I need to use in SharpSVN to get file information based on these two parameters?

Thanks,
Flea#

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using the builtin `SvnLookClient`.

To use this, first of all you need a `SvnLookOrigin`. SharpSvn contains standard argument parsing that 'knows' what arguments are passed to each type of hook. This gives you access to this `SvnLookOrigin`:

```
SvnHookArguments ha; 
if (!SvnHookArguments.ParseHookArguments(args, SvnHookType.PreCommit, false, out ha))
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine("Invalid arguments");
    Environment.Exit(1);  
}
```

Getting the changed files and contents of those files based on the parsed arguments

```
using (SvnLookClient cl = new SvnLookClient())
{
    Collection<SvnChangedEventArgs> changedItems;
    cl.GetChanged(ha.LookOrigin, out changedItems);

    foreach(var item in changedItems)
    {
        if(!IsXmlFile(item)) continue;

        using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            cl.Write(ha.LookOrigin, item.Path, stream);

            VerifyXMLStream(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Write to `Console.Error` and `Environment.Exit(1)` to report errors (exit non-null).