# Checking if SVN was updated C#

Tags: c#, svn, batch-file, svn-update

I'm trying to check if the svn was updated, and I don't wish to use SharpSVN.
I'm trying to use the `Process` class.

In batch, this is what I would normally do: `svn st -u <svn path> | find "*"`

Here is my code:

```
private void checkSVN()
{
        Process newProcess= new Process();
        newProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "svn";
        newProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "";
        newProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "st -u C:\\SVN | find " + @"""*""";
        newProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        newProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        newProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(parseStandartOutput);

        newProcess.Start();
        newProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
}
private static void parseStandartOutput(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
        m_svnOutput += outLine.Data + " ";
}
```

The problem is that the `find "*"` doesn't work - The `newProcess.StartInfo.Arguments` is set to `"st -u C:\\SVN | find \"*\*""`, and that, of course, doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you want to use SharpSVN? because it looks like the best option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074891/how-to-access-file-information-in-a-pre-commit-hook-using-sharpsvn/2075198#2075198 other libraries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211765/svn-libraries-for-net

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply

```
        newProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "st -u C:\\SVN | find \"*\"";
```

Comment: Yes, I have...Same thing...The variable `m_svnOutput` which should have the results is empty, that's why I know it doesn't work. As for `newProcess.StartInfo.Arguments` - I still get `"st -u C:\\SVN | find \"*\*""` there...